# Inserting images behind or in front of text using python-docx

Tags: python, image, addition, docx

i'm new here with you

and I've a question :it's about python-docx

I want just to insert images or icon(png,ico...) behind the text or in front of the text,
using python-docx.
Can you tell me how to add floating pictures ?

thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add images behind or in front of text with custom layout positioning in a Word document, you may consider using a different library such as python-pptx, which provides more advanced layout capabilities for PowerPoint presentations.

However, if you specifically require python-docx for your task and floating images are not a strict requirement, you can still achieve a similar effect by using tables. Here's an example of how you can position an image in relation to text using a table in python-docx.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

# Create a new document
document = Document()

# Add a table with two columns
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)

# Add an image to the first cell
cell = table.cell(0, 0)
image_path = 'image.png'
cell.add_paragraph().add_run().add_picture(image_path, width=Inches(1.5))

# Add text to the second cell
cell = table.cell(0, 1)
cell.text = "Hello, world!"

# Save the document
document.save('output.docx')
```

In this example, an image is added to the first cell of a table, and the text is added to the second cell. By adjusting the table layout and formatting, you can position the image relative to the text as needed.

While this approach doesn't provide the same flexibility as floating images, it can help you achieve a similar effect within the constraints of python-docx.